# Correct regalia when collecting a masters degree but you already hold a doctorate

Tags: united-states, graduation, academic-dress

What is the correct regalia to wear in the United States when you receive a Masters degree but you have previously earned a doctorate. (And you own your doctoral regalia )

I.e. you’re a physician and you’ve earned a masters in anthropology for fun/enrichment

Would it be appropriate to wear your doctoral robe? Masters robe?

Comment: Do such students often actually even bother to walk? I expect the graduation of most phds in my department consists of a handshake and a “congratulations, doctor” after their defense.

Comment: Regardless, is this a potential duplicate: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/104451/117407

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What graduation gown should a PhD-holder wear when later receiving a Master's in another field?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/104451/what-graduation-gown-should-a-phd-holder-wear-when-later-receiving-a-masters-in)